# Rails Heroku How to Tell if an Image File Exists in the

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm using `rails 6.1.4` and `ruby 3.1.1`

My app is on Heroku.  I have several images in my `assets/images` directory, but I cannot get some of them to show when I deploy to live.  Other images in the app show, so I'm betting the ranch it's a code thing on my part.  All images show on my local machine.

The app matches an image in `assets/images/badges/` with an `image_name` in the `Badge` model. Currently there is NOT an image in `assets/images/badges/` for every `Badge.image_name`.

A helper gets the images that match the image_names and send the names to the view in an array. But, if an image does not exist, I do not want to show a `broken-image` icon. So, I use `if Rails.application.assets.find_asset(image_path) != nil` to test for the image's existence, before adding it to the array. My guess is this is the problem area and I don't know how else to test for an image being in the `assets/images/badges` directory.

Code:

```
app/images/badges/ (just listing 3 here)

boxing-1-bronze-150.png
boxing-1-gold-150.png
boxing-1-silver-150.png
...
```

I've logged into heroku and can list the `app/images/badges` directory and I see these images are there and are named correctly.

```
badges_helprer.rb

badge_images = []

if badges 
  badges.uniq!
  badges.each do |b|
    image_path = "badges/#{b.image_name}"
    if Rails.application.assets.find_asset(image_path) != nil
      badge_images << image_path
    end
  end
end

return badge_images
```

View:

```
students/show

<% badges = get_badges_for_student(@student) %>

 <% if badges %>

   <% b_count = 0 %> 
   <% badges.each do |b| %>
     <% if b_count == 3 %>  <!-- 3 images per row -->
       <br />
       <% b_count = 0 %>
     <% end %>
     <%= image_tag(b) %>
     <% b_count += 1 %>
   <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

As a test on my show view, I created an image tag for one of the images I know is there.

```
<p>Test: <%= image_tag("badges/boxing-1-gold-150.png") %></p>
```

It shows, so I go back to the helper page and am betting the line: `if Rails.application.assets.find_asset(image_path) != nil` is not working the way I think it should.

Is there a better way to test for an image file in the `assets/images/badges/` directory.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know about using `onerror` in the `img` tag? Probably make this far simpler than what you're trying to do. Edit: there's also the `<object>` wrapper option. Google "html img fallback"

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
if File.exists?(Rails.root.join('app','assets','images','badges',image_name))
```

Note: `Rails.root` on Heroku shows `app-name/app` so the above `Rails.root.join('app','assets','images','badges',image_name)` displays  `app/app/assets...` when I print it out in a view. odd!! But I guess it knows how to navigate to the correct path.